# "No Route to Host" when making HTTP call to Linux server

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, port, http

I'm trying to configure a Linux server (NGINX) to allow HTTP requests through port 80 and it just doesn't seem to budge.

When I run `curl localhost:80` from within the server, I get the correct response. But as soon as I change `localhost` to the public IP address, it gives the following error: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to <ip> port 80: No route to host`. Here are the things I've tried:

1. `ping <ip>` works
2. `sudo ufw disable` to temporarily disable the server firewall (I also added `80/tcp` to my allowed `ufw` list. Output of `sudo ufw status`:

```
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere                  
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere                  
443                        ALLOW       Anywhere                  
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
443 (v6)                   ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

3. `netstat -ltn` shows port 80 being listened to:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

If it helps, here is my NGINX configuration (and yes, NGINX is live XD):

```
upstream django {
        server 127.0.0.1:5000;
#        server unix:///home/ubuntu/app/lyricschords/lyricschords.sock;
        #server unix:///home/ubuntu/lyrics-chords/lyrics-chords.sock;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name 127.0.0.1 localhost <ip>;

        location /media/ {
                alias /home/ubuntu/app/lyricschords/media/;
        }

        location /static/ {
                alias /home/ubuntu/app/lyricschords/static/;
        }

        location / {
                uwsgi_pass django;
                include /etc/nginx/uwsgi_params;
        }
}
```

I also have Django running on port 5000 via uWSGI.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: where on the network are you testing this from, and are you on the inside of the same router that has the public IP you are using? when forwarding ports, if you want to test the service via the public IP of the router from within the same LAN, you need a configuration called Hairpin NAT on the router. Most home/SOHO grade routers don't offer that feature, and enterprise grade routers usually need to be specifically configured to allow hairpinning/loopback NAT. Just a thought.

Comment: @FrankThomas Hmm, I asked a friend of mine to try the request and it didn't work. An interesting thing though is that running `Nmap <ip>` shows `80/tcp  closed http`. Does this perhaps help?

Comment: I'm assuming it means that my server isn't listening to port 80. Would it perhaps be a NGINX issue then?

Comment: no, your netstat output shows 80 listening, and bound to all IP interfaces (0.0.0.0). I see you found the issue to be your servers local firewall.  that issue does match up with the findings you presented. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using Oracle, this post ended up solving things: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62326988/cant-access-oracle-cloud-always-free-compute-http-port. Turned out just to be a firewall issue

Comment: This was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If localhost:80 works but the external IP does not, then the webserver is at least listening on port 80, but either it is listening on localhost only or it is firewalled on the public IP.

You can use tools like `netstat -lt` or `ss -lt` to get a list of ports being listend to, and look for `*:http` or `[::]:http` which indicates listening on the wildcard ip address.  If instead you see `127.0.0.1:http` then it is only listening on the local ip address.  Or you can check your web server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; is there a way to tell which one it is?

Comment: If you want to know how to check your firewall configuration, you should ask another question, and include your operating system version and which host firewall (firewalld, ufw, iptables, etc.) you are using.